# Eclipse Linux cannot recognize Spring boot project as Eclipse Window

Tags: java, linux, spring, eclipse

I am trying to create a spring boot project from start.spring.io then open it by Eclipse RCP Neon 1 (Window version). It's work well.

[image]

But Linux Eclipse (also RCP Neon 1) does not showing as expected.

[image]

As you can see, the tree need to be expanded 6 times to reach the first java class which I found really inconvenient. Is there anyway to make Eclipse Linux organize the project again?

I try to view the project on both "Package Explorer" and "Project Explorer", either are same as image.

Comment: One seems to understand that it's a Maven Java project, the other does not.

Answer (score 5):

Problem solved, just right click project: "Maven -> Update Project-> OK".

Also, I can't find "project facet" in "Properties", which is really weird. But I don't need it anyway
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can resolve this issue by trying this just right click on your project > properties > Project facet > choose convert to faceted format
[image]